# URL to add gadget to Google Sites Start Page

Tags: google-workspace, google-classic-sites, gadget

What would the URL be to link to the Google Apps Sites Start Page that allows you add a specific gadget to your page?

For example, if I want to add a widget to a regular iGoogle page, I use this:
http://www.google.com/ig/adde?moduleurl=URLTOMYGADGETXMLGOESHERE

However, I need to know what the URL would be for Google Sites Start Page.  I have tried all sorts of variations on that URL with the domain of our Google Apps page, as well as just about everything with partnerpages and I can't seem to find it.

**Edit:** Alternatively, being able to add a section of gadgets to the gadgets directory would be sufficient.

Comment: The [tag:google-sites] should be included as the questions is about a web page type of Google Sites, even if it's not available for the consumer edition, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL and format for adding an external gadget to your iGoogle page will be something like this:

`http://fusion.google.com/add?moduleurl=http%3A//www.domain.com/path/gadget.xml`

I think as long as your user is logged into the correct google account/site all should go well.

**Edit:** The user following the link to add such a gadget must be logged in to google with the desired google apps user as their primary/first login in that browser session. Adding pages to the apps version of iGoogle does not seem to work if the apps login is a secondary login using the multiple-logins feature of google accounts.

**Edit 2:** To summarize findings of the comments so far, this appears to have to do with differences in the way google account logins are handled for different editions or versions of the apps platform.

Comment: This works (and redirects to the URL in my post) for regular Google accounts, but does not work with Google Apps iGoogle pages, nor Google Apps Google Sites Start Pages.

Comment: @brad: I just tested this with a google-apps on one of my client's domains and successfully added a gadget to the Apps iGoogle home page using that link. Are you perhaps signing in to google using the "multiple logins" feature where your apps account is a secondary login instead of being the primary/first one you logged in with in your browser session?

Comment: No, but strangely enough, the "multiple accounts" feature doesn't work for us, nor is it needed.  We can use a regular Google account as well as a Google Apps account simultaneously in the same browser session, as if that transition to using the same cookie never existed.  For testing your URL, I logged out of my regular Google account first, and I just get prompted to login as if I wasn't logged in at all.  Perhaps our domain isn't migrated to this new cookie system yet?

Comment: @brad: Very strange indeed! Generally logging into two google accounts in the same browser session is very problematic -- I think the fact that you can do that is your real problem, not a special URL format. When you got propted to login "as if you weren't logged in at all" did you try giving it your full user@hosted-domain.tld and password for the apps site in question?

Comment: @brad: If the login suggestion in my previous comment doesn't work, you might try switching your google apps hosting account to the Next-Generation option in the Domain-Settings section of your control panel.

Comment: I am unable to login with my Google Apps account (including @domainame.com) at any normal Google login box, including the one that shows up after logging out of iGoogle.  Our domain is set to next gen.  We also have "Enable pre-release features" turned on.

Comment: @brad: Ok this is getting more puzzling, not less. I can open a clean browser with no cookies or history (or a chrome incognito window), click on my link above with a valid gadget url. I get taken to a google login screen. If I enter caleb@my-clients-domain.com and my password for that google apps hosted domain I get taken to my iGoogle "start page" for that domain. I am assuming you have "start pages" enabled as one of the google-apps features for this domain?

Comment: Our start page went away over the summer on its own.  We now have iGoogle as a start page, and yes that is enabled.  I am currently in the process of building a new start page with Google Sites to give us a bit more control.  This is Google Apps for Education, if that makes a difference.  Yes, I am as confused as you are.

Comment: @brad: Let me clarify: when I said "start page", what I am seeing is an iGoogle home page. The headers across the top are inconsitent between the control panel, the gmail, the iGoogle, sites etc. Sometimes it calls it "web" sometimes it calls it "home", sometimes "start page", but it's an iGoogle page for my domain. A little DNS magic also makes it so that start.myclientsdomain.com takes people to that iGoogle page. Have you done that bit? For reference I'm using the standard edition Google Apps For My Domain product, not the premium or edu. Next-Gen is selected but prerelease features is not.

Comment: Yes, we're on the same page.  We are using the same start page as you.  We also have set up a hostname for it on our domain, just as you have.  Perhaps there are more differences between the editions of Google Apps than I thought.

Comment: @brad: Pshaw! I didn't expect this to be so complicated. You might be right about differences between editions; but my puzzled brain isn't happy about the whole thing. Would you mind setting me up a temporary account inside your domain to try the login end of things from here? We can do this out of the public eye if you like, my name at alerque.com. If not I understand.

Comment: Sadly, this isn't something I will be able to do. I think I am going to take a new approach.  I am going to try to figure out this feed server client tool thing to control what gadgets appear in our gadget directory.  I think that will work better anyway.  Thanks so much for your efforts on this one!  I am awarding you the +100 bounty.

Comment: There were a lot of changes since 2010 and the answer is about iGoogle not the Google Sites Start Page.

Comment: @Rubén The question was originally about iGoogle and that's what I answered. Not only has the question morphed but so has Google's offerings.

Comment: @Caled Are you considering to update your answer?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, at this time it's not possible to add a gadget to a Google Sites Start Page by using a URL.

Instead the developer have to give the instructions to their users about how to add gadgets. It's worth to say that (from [3])...

> Google Apps administrators can use a open source project, the Feed
>   Server Client Tool (FSCT) to control which gadgets appear in the
>   Google Sites gadget directory for their domain. Before beginning, make
>   sure you are running Java 1.6 (you can check your version by running
>   the "java -version" command)

**References**
1. [Gadgets API - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gadgets/)
2. [Web Apps and Google Sites Gadgets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
3. [Administer Gadgets in Google Sites - Google Apps Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/168329?hl=en)